# Show tooltip and keep it visible

Tags: highcharts

Whenever the user "mouse out" my chart, I would like a tooltip to automatically appear above one point and stay visible until the mouse returns above the chart.

```
series: {
  events: {
    mouseOut: function() {
      chart.series[0].data.refresh(0);
  }
}
```

The code above works, but the tooltip disappear after a second or two.  I want it to stay visible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This reassigning of the `reset` function should help to achieve wanted result.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pu9g2dft/

```
  Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function() {
    return undefined;
  };
```